# Did Parashurama ever object to the way his students, Bhishma, Drona and Karna were killed by the Pandavas?

Tags: mahabharata, dharma, karna, parashurama, bhishma

I am curious to know what/if Lord Parashurama had thought about the way all his shishyas (students/disciples), Bhishma, Drona and Karna, died in the Mahabharata war.

Did he object to the way they were killed by the Pandavas since they were not holding any weapons at the time?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by 'What Lord Parashurama said when his all his shisyas died in Mahabharata when they had no weapons in their hands'? Are you talking about the adharma aspect of it? Why will Parashurama say anything?

Comment: @sv. - I am not really talking about Adharma aspect but as they were Shishya of Parashurama, he might object the way his Shishyas was killed?

Comment: 'he might object the way his Shishyas were killed' - so you are in fact talking about dharma/adharma aspect of it. You can replace one of the tags with the 'dharma' tag. Also, change the title to: Did Parashurama ever object to the way his disciples, Karna, Drona and Bhishma were killed by the Pandavas?

Comment: @sv. - Even you can edit the question.

Answer (score 3):

Mahabharata did not say anything about his reaction after hearing the news of deaths of his disciples Bhishma, Drona and Karna.

Let us examine each case separately.

1. When Parasurama fought with Bhishma on account of Amba, [for 23 days](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m05/m05185.htm),  he could not defeat Bhishma. When Bhishma was about to discharge [Praswapa weapon](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m05/m05188.htm), Sage Narada stopped him, stating that he should not kill his preceptor.

In a reconciliation process, [Jamadagni and his forefathers advised him](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m05/m05188.htm) as follows:

> **Study (of the Vedas) and practice of vows are the highest wealth of
> Brahmanas!** For some reason, before 'this, thou hadst been ordered by
> us to take up weapons. Thou hadst then perpetrated that terrible and
> unbecoming feat. Let this battle with Bhishma be thy very last, for
> enough of it thou hadst already.
>
> O thou of mighty arms, leave the combat. Blessed be thou, ***let this be
> the very last instance of thy taking up the bow!*** O invincible one,
> throw thy bow aside, and practice ascetic austerities
>
> That foremost of the Pandavas, ***Arjuna***, the mighty son of Indra, hath
> been **ordained by the Self-create to be the slayer of Bhishma**!'

So Parasurama knew beforehand that Arjuna will be the cause of elimination of Bhishma.  So he should not have any qualms at the death of Bhishma.

---

2. In order to demoralise Drona, Bhimasena killed an elephant with the name Aswatthaman, and proclaimed before Drona that he had killed Aswatthaman.  Drona thought it was Aswatthaman, his son, but still he continued his battle.

[Beholding Drona stationed on the field](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m07/m07187.htm#fn_251) for the extermination of the Kshatriya race, the Rishis Viswamitra, and Jamadagni, and Bharadwaja, and Gautama, and Vasishtha, and Kasyapa, and Atri, and the Srikatas, the Prisnis, Garga, the Valkhilyas, the Marichis, **the descendants of Bhrigu** and Angiras, and diverse other sages of subtle forms quickly came thither, with the Bearer of sacrificial libations at their head, and, desirous of taking Drona unto the region of Brahman, addressed Drona, that ornament of battle, and said,

> 'Thou art fighting **unrighteously**. The hour of thy death is come.
> Laying aside thy weapons in battle, O Drona, behold us stationed here.
> After this, it behoveth thee not to perpetrate such exceedingly cruel
> deeds.
>
> Thou art versed in the Vedas and their branches. Thou art devoted to
> the duties enjoined by truth, especially, ***thou art a Brahmana***.
> Such acts do not become thee. ***Lay aside thy weapons***. Drive away
> the film of error that shrouds thee. Adhere now to the eternal path.
> The period for which thou art to dwell in the world of men is now
> full. Thou hast, with the Brahma weapon, burnt men on earth that are
> unacquainted with weapons.
>
> This act that thou hast perpetrated, O regenerate one, is not
> righteous. Lay aside thy weapons in battle without delay, O Drona, do
> not wait longer on earth. Do not, O regenerate one, perpetrate such a
> sinful act.'

Being a brAhmana, Drona should not have acted like a kshatriya. He took weapons and killed many warriors like a kshatriya.  That was why the rishis warned him to desist from doing further, including the  **descendants of Bhrigu**.

We have to remember that Parasurama also a **descendant of Bhrigu**.

As Drona did a mistake, unbecoming of a brAhmana and took the path of a kshatriya, Parasurama, who himself decided not to take bow after the war with Bhishma, should not have regrets at the death of Drona.

---

3. As far as Karna is concerned, we have to remember that Karna learnt usage of Divine weapons from Parasurama, by telling untruth that he was a brAhmana.  So Parasurama should not have regretted for the death of Karna.

---

Comment: This is nonsense.

Comment: yeah. Bhishma just ascended to Vasu Loka, Swarga and then to Vaikuntha I think

Comment: But I think Parashurama was sad knowing the condition of Bhishma

Comment: It's not nonsense very good answer.

Answer (score 0):

No mention in mahabharat.Also your question is faulty.Only Drona was killed unarmed.Bhishma was still fighting with bow ,he was never unarmed.Also karna was never unarmed according to BORI critical edition of mahabharat.

Comment: If he had weapons there was no option to kill him because his Dhanush itself was devine.

Comment: Vijay danush doesn't guarantee victory.Bhima fairly defeated Karna even though he had Vijaya

Comment: no he did not. karna was fighting with an ordinary bow